# Spring Boot tries to close embedded database twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I'm using an H2 embedded database for testing, and after the tests complete, I'm seeing the system trying to close the database twice and then it hangs waiting on the last log line shown here:

```
...
2019-07-14 07:58:47.115  INFO 44844 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-07-14 07:58:47.115  INFO 44844 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-07-14 07:58:47.116  INFO 44844 --- [       Thread-2] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2019-07-14 07:58:47.116  INFO 44844 --- [       Thread-4] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2019-07-14 07:58:47.117  INFO 44844 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
2019-07-14 07:58:47.117  INFO 44844 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
```

This is happening with Spring Boot 2.1.5 and 2.1.6

In the test class I set up the database this way

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.yml")
@Slf4j
public class DBTest {

...
  static EmbeddedDatabase informixDB;
  static JdbcTemplate informixJDBCTemplate;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void initDb() {
    informixDB = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    informixJDBCTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(informixDB);
    ClassPathResource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("data/informix/InformixUp.sql");
    DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, informixDB);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void dropDb() {
    ClassPathResource drop = new ClassPathResource("data/informix/InformixDown.sql");
    DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(drop);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, informixDB);
  }
```

I have this in my test/application.yml though it seems to be being ignored

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  h2:
    console:
      path: /h2-console
      enabled: true
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
#        trace: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:informixDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
    username: sa
    password:
```

Comment: h2 will automatically close and drop everything when the jvm is closed, thats its default state so you don't need to manually clean up after you. If you wish to change this behaviour you have to configure it http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#do_not_close_on_exit

Comment: After commenting out the @AfterClass method, I still see the same problem...

Comment: well you are starting up your own db in the beforeClass and then tearing it down in the after, all this is automatically done by spring if you have configured to use h2 in your application.yml

Comment: Oic, well, the reasoning is that soon, I want to use two different databases in the same test.  One is Informix and one is Mysql.

Comment: I see now, if I want to do it this way, I have to actually say informixDB.shutdown() in @AfterClass and remove the configuration from application.yml